# Foreign Syntax - Need Help Understanding

Tags: java, syntax, programming-languages

So I've been programming a few years now, so I'm not really new - but I just started learning Java (from C++). While learning a library and looking through it's examples (jMonkeyEngine3 if you must know) I came across foreign syntax that I can't seem to find any documentation on.

Here's the code (all of it is within the scope of a class):

```
/** Custom Keybinding: Map named actions to inputs. */
private void initKeys() {
  // You can map one or several inputs to one named action
  inputManager.addMapping("Pause",  new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_P));
  inputManager.addMapping("Left",   new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_J));
  inputManager.addMapping("Right",  new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_K));
  inputManager.addMapping("Rotate", new KeyTrigger(KeyInput.KEY_SPACE),
                                    new MouseButtonTrigger(MouseInput.BUTTON_LEFT));
  // Add the names to the action listener.
  inputManager.addListener(actionListener, new String[]{"Pause"});
  inputManager.addListener(analogListener, new String[]{"Left", "Right", "Rotate"});

}

private ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
  public void onAction(String name, boolean keyPressed, float tpf) {
    if (name.equals("Pause") && !keyPressed) {
      isRunning = !isRunning;
    }
  }
};
```

I'm guessing that the defining piece (15) creates an object of ActionListener with a private scope named actionListener using the default constructor inside the class - then overrides/implements an onAction method in itself. Then in it's implementation (11) it's simply referencing this created object? Would that be correct?

Thanks so much for the clarification.

Comment: It's customary to include the code in your question instead of linking to an outside resource. It keeps everything in one place and easier for everyone to see. I've pulled it in for you. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Oh, I'm quite sorry. I'll keep that in mind next time!

Answer (score 2):

> I'm guessing that the defining piece (15) creates an object of ActionListener

That syntax is what's known as an [anonymous inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html). It's as close as you can get to a closure or lambda expression in Java until JDK 8 comes around. You're basically creating a new class on the fly. It's effectively the same as if you'd said:

```
private ActionListener actionListener = new MyActionListener();

class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
    public void onAction(String name, boolean keyPressed, float tpf) {
        if (name.equals("Pause") && !keyPressed) {
            isRunning = !isRunning;
        }
    }
}
```

The other way just uses less lines.

> with a private scope

It's not exactly that the object is private. Private is just the visibility of the field that holds the reference to the object. The object itself can be handed around anywhere, as any object can.

> named actionListener

That's the name of the field that holds a reference to the created ActionListener.

> using the default constructor inside the class

Actually, ActionListener is an interface and therefore has no constructors. Even the anonymous inner class technically doesn't have a default constructor. Instead, it has an ["anonymous constructor"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5.1).